# running a function within a function and object not being found

Tags: r

I am embarrassed that I'm asking this question, and I wonder if it has something fundamental to do with scoping that I'm not understanding.

i have two functions, `beta` and `alpha`

```
beta <- function(b) {
  foo <- b + x
  print(foo)
}
```

and

```
alpha <- function(a) {
  x <- a + 5
  print(x)
  beta(2)
}
```

When I run `alpha(1)` I'm expecting the output of `beta` to be 8. However, I get an error message about object 'x' not being found.

Question:  shouldn't `beta` know that x is 6?  I think I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that both `alpha` and `beta` are declared inside the Global Environment.

Every function looks for unknown objects into the parent environment.
`beta`'s parent environment is the global environment, so when `x` is called `beta` will look for `x` in the Global Environment: it can't "see" what was created inside `alpha`'s environment.

It would work as you expect:

- if you declare `beta` inside `alpha` environment:

```r
alpha <- function(a) {
  beta <- function(b) {
    foo <- b + x
    print(foo)
  }
  x <- a + 5
  print(x)
  beta(2)
}
alpha(1)
#> [1] 6
#> [1] 8
```

- or if you tell `beta` in which environment it should look for `x`:

```r
beta <- function(b, env = parent.frame()) {
  
  x <- get("x", envir = env)
  foo <- b + x
  print(foo)

}

alpha <- function(a) {
  
  x <- a + 5
  print(x)
  beta(2) # by default beta takes alpha's environment as parent frame!

}

alpha(1)
#> [1] 6
#> [1] 8
```

There are also other options, like assigning `x` to the alpha's parent environment, but I wouldn't do that.

```r
beta <- function(b) {
  
  foo <- b + x
  print(foo)
  
}

alpha <- function(a) {
  
  x <<- a + 5
  print(x)
  beta(2)
  
}

alpha(1)
#> [1] 6
#> [1] 8
```

---

I would suggest you to have a look at [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html).

Comment: Thank you!  I'm embarrassed that I've been using R for all these years but didn't know these principals.

Answer (score 2):

`R` uses [lexical scoping](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#lexical-scoping). That means that values are first looked up in the function itself and then in the environment where the function was defined.

When you define both `alpha` and `beta` in the global environment, `beta` looks up `x` in the global environment.

```r
beta <- function(b) {
  foo <- b + x
  print(foo)
}

alpha <- function(a) {
  x <- a + 5
  print(x)
  beta(2)
}

alpha(1)
#> [1] 6
#> Error in beta(2): object 'x' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

In contrast, if you define `beta` within `alpha`, `x` is found (because `x` is also defined in the environment where `beta` is defined):

```r
alpha <- function(a) {
  x <- a + 5
  print(x)
  
  beta <- function(b) {
    foo <- b + x
    print(foo)
  }
  beta(2)
}

alpha(1)
#> [1] 6
#> [1] 8
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

What about specifying `x` in `beta()`?

```
beta <- function(b, x) {
  foo <- b + x
  print(foo)
}


alpha <- function(a) {
  x <- a + 5
  print(x)
  beta(2, x)
}

alpha(1)
# [1] 6
# [1] 8
```